# C Header File: Macro Expansion without Std Library

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am looking to expand the macros i have in c header files, but thus far i am also getting a standard library. My ~200 line files expand to 60k line files (~30k lines of it is white space), of which i only want to use the expanded original ~200 lines.

Is there a flag that allows me to not expand the standard library?

Command used at present: `cl myHeader.h /E > __test.h`

example of the kind of line refs that get expanded into my processed header (omitting the expanded code):
`#line 688 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\include\\string"`

My end use case is to parse the expanded headers, I believe (but cannot be certain) that most of the macros are simple `#define FOO 42` type expansions for populating array sizes. If I can't get `cl` to stop inserting the standard library, do I have any other options?

Worst case I can work from the bottom upwards and clip the file on `#line <num> <path>` not matching my file's path, but that seems very inelegant.

Using MSVC on Windows.

Comment: A) Show us what file you're talking about or a *minimal version that reproduces the issue*. B) You generally don't get expansion unless you `#include` something, in which case obviously you will have more lines.

Comment: Did you try to provide empty header files of the same name as the standard libraries' and to change the list of include search paths? This sounds like a hack, but you want it, and it will be used just for this purpose. To separate these header files, you should put them in an own directory.

Comment: For the sole purpose of pre-processing you can simply comment out the library includes. Or at least that works on many other compilers, not sure about MSVC.

Comment: @Lundin you're right, the root cause is `#include <string>`. I had not thought of nixing it, thinking it would result in errors. (one function in the file is using `std::string`). It doesn't appear to mind at all for the pre-processor. Thank you, you should/ought to set that as the answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Lundin in the comments above.

I had incorrectly assumed that commenting out includes that are required for compilation would impede the preprocessor. It doesn't care whatsoever. Stripping troublesome `#includes` is a very easy way to get macro-expanded headers. It will still have the `#line <number> <path>` and blank lines, but these are trivial to strip out.